# Error in PowerShell "cannot convert the value of type System.String to type..."

Tags: string, powershell, system, vmware

I want to create VMware SRM protection group with PowerCLI and VMware SRM module.

Basically I have to pass just two variables, one is the name of that group, and the other is one or more datastores which I'm getting not from PowerShell, in a form of array.

```
$PG_name = "some_PG_name"

$Datastores_test = "datastore1"
or
$Datastores_test = ['datastore1']
or 
$Datastores_test = ['datastore1','datastore2']
or 
$Datastores_test = @('datastore1','datastore2')
```

I tried with all 4 variants above and got the same error. it fails at "datastore1" regardless is it that the only value (even if it's just string and not in an array), or there are one or more values in the array.

And here is the command that should be doing the job:

```
New-SrmProtectionGroup -Name $PG_name -ArrayReplication -Datastores $Datastores_test
```

Error is:

```
  Cannot convert the "datastore1" value of type "System.String" to type "VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Types.V1.DatastoreManagement.Datastore".
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Try doing `$Datastores_test = Get-DataStore -Name 'datastore1','datastore2'`

Comment: Problem is that I don't really know what will be datastore names, so I cannot hardcode it. It should somehow call this array of strings.

Comment: I tried this $Datastores = ['datastore1','datastore2'] and $Datastores_test = Get-DataStore -Name $Datastores and then New-SrmProtectionGroup -Name $PG_name -ArrayReplication -Datastores $Datastores_test and it's not working but now different error 
Exception calling "CreateAbrProtectionGroup" with "4" argument(s): "
Required parameter datastores is missing

Comment: yeah, but you can do `Get-DataStore -Name $listOfDatastoreNames`. No idea about the second exception though, I'd probably contact VMWare support :)

Comment: Can you tell me how do you mark code when you are writing update here so it is different from the non-code?

Comment: Backticks ` on either side

Comment: Double check that after the `Get-DataStore` call `$Datastores` is not simply empty, that would explain the error.

Comment: It's not empty. I am getting info for two datastores when doing `$Datastores = @("datastore1","datastore2")` and then `Get-Datastore -Name $Datastores`

Comment: But, when I use that in `New-SrmProtectionGroup -Name $PG_name -ArrayReplication -Datastores $Datastores_test` error is `Exception calling "CreateAbrProtectionGroup" with "4" argument(s): "A specified parameter was not correct."` and then below `You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.`

Comment: Looks like an internal screwup, but even so, you can try `Set-StrictMode -Version 5` and try the whole thing again just in case a more insightful error is caught earlier this way.

Comment: Not working with Set-StrictMode neither.